# What does ".=" in vim scripts mean?

Tags: vim

I've often seen assignments to variables of the form "let s.='something'" Here's the specific piece of code in a vim script that I've been struggling to understand:

```
let s .= '%' . i . 'T'
let s .= (i == t ? '%1*' : '%2*')
let s .= ' '
let s .= i . ':'
let s .= winnr . '/' . tabpagewinnr(i,'$')
let s .= ' %*'
let s .= (i == t ? '%#TabLineSel#' : '%#TabLine#')
```

The code adds the tab number (`i`) and viewport number (`winnr` of `tabpagewinnr(i,'$')`) to the tab name, so that it looks something like "1: 2/4 Buffer name". From the looks of it, the `.=` operation seems to be appending stuff to `s`. But then, I don't understand what the first two lines do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.=` is the string concatenation shortcut operator. It's basically `s = s . somethingelse`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

vim's [online](https://vimhelp.org/) [help](https://vimhelp.org/helphelp.txt.html#help) is your friend:

[`:h .=`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Alet.%3D)

> ```
>  :let {var} .= {expr1}    Like ":let {var} = {var} . {expr1}".
> ```

[`:h expr-.`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-.)

> ```
>  expr6 .   expr6 ..   String concatenation
> ```

[`:h expr1`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr1) (well - this is a little hard to find):

> ```
>  expr2 ? expr1 : expr1
> ```

> ```
>  The expression before the '?' is evaluated to a number.  If it evaluates to TRUE, the result is the value of the expression between the '?' and ':', otherwise the result is the value of the expression after the ':'.
> ```

```
 Example:
   :echo lnum == 1 ? "top" : lnum
```

> 

```
  Since the first expression is an "expr2", it cannot contain another ?:.  The
  other two expressions can, thus allow for recursive use of ?:.
  Example:
    :echo lnum == 1 ? "top" : lnum == 1000 ? "last" : lnum
```

> 

```
  To keep this readable, using |line-continuation| is suggested:
    :echo lnum == 1
    :\  ? "top"
    :\  : lnum == 1000
    :\      ? "last"
    :\      : lnum
```

> 

```
  You should always put a space before the ':', otherwise it can be mistaken for
  use in a variable such as "a:1".
```

Answer (score 1):

One at a time:

```
let s .= '%' . i . 'T'
```

Assuming i=9 and s="bleah", s will now be "bleah%9T"

```
let s .= (i == t ? '%1*' : '%2*')
```

This is the familiar ternary operator from C. If t==9, then s is now "bleah%9T%1*". If t is anything *but* 9, then s is now "bleah%9T%2*"